# Launch screen terminals with set directory

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

How can I get my screen session to open different terminals in different directories on login?

For example,
In my `.screenrc` file I have the following:

```
screen -t bash0
screen -t bash1
screen -t bash2
```

How do I point bash0 to have a start location of `~/folder0`, bash1 to `~/folder1`, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
screen -t bash0 sh -c 'cd ~/folder0; bash' 
screen -t bash1 sh -c 'cd ~/folder1; bash'
screen -t bash2 sh -c 'cd ~/folder1; bash'
```